# Find change of Basis matrix from $B_{1}$ and $B_{2}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $$B_{1}= \begin{pmatrix} 
2 & 1 \\
1 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
\;\;\;\;\;\;  B_{2} = \begin{pmatrix}
5 & 3 \\
7 & 4
\end{pmatrix}
$$

How would I solve this without the coordinate vector? I couldn't find a solution in my textbook. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Suppose you have a vector $X=[x_1 \,x_2]^T$
You want a matrix $B$ such that $B[B_1X] = [BB_1]X = B_2X$. Since $X$ is arbitrary, that means $BB_1=B_2$.